# Android Map api v2 "unfortunately appname has stopped"

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-api-2

Hi i followed [this](http://mobisys.in/blog/2012/12/google-rolls-out-android-maps-api-v2/#comment-29177) tutorial and others but i still having a problem. when i running my app shows "unfortunately   appname has  stopped" 
this is my log

```
12-17 00:09:03.928: E/AndroidRuntime(3536): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-17 00:09:03.928: E/AndroidRuntime(3536): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.minimapa/com.example.minimapa.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
12-17 00:09:03.928: E/AndroidRuntime(3536):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1659)
12-17 00:09:03.928: E/AndroidRuntime(3536):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
12-17 00:09:03.928: E/AndroidRuntime(3536):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
12-17 00:09:03.928: E/AndroidRuntime(3536):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
12-17 00:09:03.928: E/AndroidRuntime(3536):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-17 00:09:03.928: E/AndroidRuntime(3536):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-17 00:09:03.928: E/AndroidRuntime(3536):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
12-17 00:09:03.928: E/AndroidRuntime(3536):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-17 00:09:03.928: E/AndroidRuntime(3536):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-17 00:09:03.928: E/AndroidRuntime(3536):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
12-17 00:09:03.928: E/AndroidRuntime(3536):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
12-17 00:09:03.928: E/AndroidRuntime(3536):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-17 00:09:03.928: E/AndroidRuntime(3536): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
12-17 00:09:03.928: E/AndroidRuntime(3536):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:587)
12-17 00:09:03.928: E/AndroidRuntime(3536):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
12-17 00:09:03.928: E/AndroidRuntime(3536):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
12-17 00:09:03.928: E/AndroidRuntime(3536):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
12-17 00:09:03.928: E/AndroidRuntime(3536):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
12-17 00:09:03.928: E/AndroidRuntime(3536):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:227)
12-17 00:09:03.928: E/AndroidRuntime(3536):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
12-17 00:09:03.928: E/AndroidRuntime(3536):     at com.example.minimapa.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
12-17 00:09:03.928: E/AndroidRuntime(3536):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-17 00:09:03.928: E/AndroidRuntime(3536):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
```

Comment: in which device version you are compiling this code. and this error is occurred due to fragment inflate. Check the fragment supported jar is included and run it again.

Comment: Check your code `at com.example.minimapa.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)`

Comment: post full code... ! Have you imported the Google Play Services properly ??